# how to select menu item as per the scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in my code with scroll and active menu,....
Here is my code and fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ajm7Ljwu/

just check the 3 and 4th menu of the page while scrolling down and up..
please help me... Thanks (please don't give any solution related to jquery)

> css

```
<style type="text/css">
                    a{
                        position: fixed;
                    }
                    div{
                        float:left;
                        width:100px;
                    }
                    p{
                        height:500px;
                    }
                </style>
```

> html

```
   <div>
        <a href="" class="ele elemMe1">1</a><br>
        <a href="" class="ele elemMe2">2</a><br>
        <a href="" class="ele elemMe3">3</a><br>
        <a href="" class="ele elemMe4">4</a><br>
    </div>

    <div>   
        <p class="elemMe" id="elemMe1">1</p>
        <p class="elemMe" id="elemMe2">2</p>
        <p class="elemMe" id="elemMe3">3</p>
        <p class="elemMe" id="elemMe4">4</p>
    </div>
```

> javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentPagePosition = pageYOffset;


        window.onscroll = function(e){
            var allDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('elemMe');
                console.log(allDiv);


                for(var i = 0; i < allDiv.length; i++){


                    if(pageYOffset > allDiv[i].offsetTop-allDiv[i].offsetHeight-100){


                        var p_id = allDiv[i].attributes['id'].value;
                        var currentMenu = document.getElementsByClassName(p_id);



                        currentMenu[0].style.color = "red";


                    }else if(pageYOffset < allDiv[i].offsetTop-allDiv[i].offsetHeight){
                        currentMenu[0].style.color = 'black';
                    }

                }


        };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var currentPagePosition = pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function(e){
  var allDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('elemMe');
  for(var i = 0; i < allDiv.length; i++){
    var p_id = allDiv[i].attributes['id'].value;
    var currentMenu = document.getElementsByClassName(p_id);
    if(pageYOffset > allDiv[i].offsetTop-allDiv[i].offsetHeight){
      currentMenu[0].style.color = "#FE0000";
    }else if(pageYOffset < allDiv[i].offsetTop-allDiv[i].offsetHeight){
      currentMenu[0].style.color = '#000';
    }else {
      currentMenu[0].style.color = 'black';
    }
  }
};
```

```css
a{
   position: fixed;
  }
  div{
   float:left;
   width:100px;
  }
  p{
   height:500px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
 <a href="" class="ele elemMe1">1</a><br>
 <a href="" class="ele elemMe2">2</a><br>
 <a href="" class="ele elemMe3">3</a><br>
 <a href="" class="ele elemMe4">4</a><br>
</div>

<div> 
 <p class="elemMe" id="elemMe1">1</p>
 <p class="elemMe" id="elemMe2">2</p>
 <p class="elemMe" id="elemMe3">3</p>
 <p class="elemMe" id="elemMe4">4</p>
</div>
```